# Django ORM filter multiple fields using 'IN' statement

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, django-orm

So I have the following model in Django:

```
class MemberLoyalty(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateField(primary_key=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, models.DO_NOTHING)
    loyalty_value = models.IntegerField()
```

My goal is to have all the tuples grouped by the member with the most recent date. There are many ways to do it, one of them is using a subquery that groups by the member with max date_time and filtering member_loyalty with its results. The working sql for this solution is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    member_loyalty
WHERE
    (date_time , member_id) IN (SELECT 
            max(date_time), member_id
        FROM
            member_loyalty
        GROUP BY member_id);
```

Another way to do this would be by joining with the subquery.

How could i translate this on a django query? I could not find a way to filter with two fields using IN, nor a way to join with a subquery using a specific ON statement.

I've tried:

```
cls.objects.values('member_id', 'loyalty_value').annotate(latest_date=Max('date_time'))
```

But it starts grouping by the loyalty_value.

Also tried building the subquery, but cant find how to join it or use it on a filter:

```
subquery = cls.objects.values('member_id').annotate(max_date=Max('date_time'))
```

Also, I am using Mysql so I can not make use of the .distinct('param') method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical [greatest-per-group](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) query. Stack-overflow even has a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/greatest-n-per-group/info) for it.

I believe the most efficient way to do it with the recent versions of Django is via a [window query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions). Something along the lines should do the trick.

```
    MemberLoyalty.objects.all().annotate(my_max=Window(
        expression=Max('date_time'),
        partition_by=F('member')
    )).filter(my_max=F('date_time'))
```

**Update**: This actually won't work, because `Window` annotations are not `filterable`. I think in order to filter on window annotation you need to wrap it inside a `Subquery`, but with `Subquery` you are actually not obligated to use a `Window` function, there is another way to do it, which is my next example.

If either MySQL or Django does not support window queries, then a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) comes into play.

```
MemberLoyalty.objects.filter(
    date_time=Subquery(
        (MemberLoyalty.objects
            .filter(member=OuterRef('member'))
            .values('member')
            .annotate(max_date=Max('date_time'))
            .values('max_date')[:1]
        )
    )
)
```

If event `Subqueries` are not available (pre Django 1.11) then this should also work:

```
MemberLoyalty.objects.annotate(
    max_date=Max('member__memberloyalty_set__date_time')
).filter(max_date=F('date_time'))
```